# How to take a high resolution screenshot on a small viewport with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.7

I am screen shoting websites on the way it looks at certain small viewports i.e. 640x580, but I want the image to be much higher resolution like maybe 3x of that size. I cannot just set_window_size(1920,1080) like that coz the website would look different.

I've tried mobile emulation that worked nice like this. at this I got image size 3x the viewport without losing quality.

```py
mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": {"width": 640, "height": 580, "pixelRatio": 3},
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19",
}

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

But at times I may need the look of a website at 800x580, or at 1000x580, or the same 640x580, with this case I need to restart/launch chrome with the new options right? (or maybe there's a way to switch/set sizes of viewport on mobile emulation?w/o restart), which is very time consuming, and I need higher throughput as I can, I need the images fast.

I tried PIL resizing the image but the quality sucks it just got stretched didn't really helped at all. Would be realy nice if someone could help, bugging me for days now.

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing the browser's virtual window:

```
driver.set_window_size(width, height)
```